# How to perform multiple root operations in a row (batch root operations)?

Tags: java, android, linux, root, batch-processing

Note: this question isn't necessary just for Android developers. It should be the same for Java developers that performed root operations on Linux too.

### Background

[**My app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) allows the user the perform various root operations (an operation that can only be performed on rooted devices).

Until now, each time the app wishes to perform a root operation, I had opened a new process using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") command.

I wish to improve the way the app works, by calling this command only once, and then writing to the outputStream and reading from the inputStream while doing so.

A similar app that does this is "[**Terminal emulator**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)". Once you type there "su" (and grant it root permission), it will allow you go perform any root operation and read any path of the device.

### The problem

It seems that only the "echo" command works, but any other command doesn't. Also, I couldn't think of a good way to separate between the root operations output.

### What I've tried

First, in order to initialize the root batching operations, I did this:

```
  process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  _inputStreamReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  _out=process.getOutputStream();
  final String testLine=Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
  _out.write(("echo "+testLine+"\n").getBytes());
  _out.flush();
  final String resultLine=_inputStreamReader.readLine();
  if(resultLine==null)
    {
    _out.write("exit \n".getBytes());
    _out.flush();
    _out.close();
    _out=null;
    _inputStreamReader.close();
    _inputStreamReader=null;
    process.waitFor();
    return false;
    }
  while(!resultLine.equals(testLine))
    resultLine=_inputStreamReader.readLine();
  return true;
```

the code above (is supposed to) ensures I have root and that I can continue working on the "_out" and "inputStreamReader" . the call to "echo" has 2 purposes : to have some fake operation being done, and to also become a starting point and a separator between commands.

Here the second purpose is fake, but for each operation that I make further, this is how I thought of handling the separation of various root operations.

Now, if I want to make another root operation (assuming the above works fine), this is an example of an operation I wish to perform :

```
_out.write(("find "+someFolderPath+"/* -type f\n").getBytes());
_out.flush();
final String line=_inputStreamReader.readLine();
```

Thing is, it gets stuck on the "readLine" part, even though it should return a list of all of the file/folders within the specified path.

This command works perfectly using the previous way I performed root operations, and it should work here too.

using "echo" before those lines and then using "readLine()" shows that it's still available, as I will still get the result line. However, trying to call "readLine()" again (after the above command) will still make it stuck.

I've also tried adding "su" (or "su -" or "su -c") before the "find" command, but it didn't help.

This is the old code, which works fine:

```
  final Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  final InputStream inputStream=p.getInputStream();
  final DataOutputStream os=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
  os.writeBytes("find "+someFolderPath+"/* -type f\n");
  os.writeBytes("exit\n");
  os.flush();
  //read from the inputstream (using BufferedReader) as much as I wish, till it ends.
```

### The question

How should I avoid re-creating new processes for root operations? Is this a good way to do it?

How can I fix the above code? What is wrong with it?

Also, Is there a good way to run multiple root operations using a single "su" command, yet without any kind of separator like the one I've used (so that I could differentiate when a new command output starts and the previous one ends).

Comment: Also, please do not downvote this without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure, that your find command is just too slow. You should run it in the different process.
[There](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/tree/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser) is great library to do this. And a [manual](http://su.chainfire.eu/#how).

Comment: no, it worked perfectly using the previous way. not only that, but other commands also get stuck (like "ls") .

Comment: In fact, your link says "Some apps need to make a lot of su calls throughout the app's lifecycle but can't batch these commands together. In such a case you should consider starting an interactive su shell and keeping it alive alongside your app", so it suggests not creating new processes for multiple operations, and use a single one instead (which is what I try to do).

Comment: However, this library looks promising. maybe I will try it out and see how it goes. I still wish to know what is the answer to my question though, since I want to learn it myself.

Comment: Also, you can +! my post. Looks like it helped :)

Comment: Yes, thank you. it helped, but I'm not marking neither of our answers as the correct ones, since they aren't answering the original question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, even though it's not quite what I wanted, and even though I wanted to learn how to do it myself, I've found that "[**libsuperuser**](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser)" library (by "ChainFire") does it much easier.

What I've asked for is called "interactive mode" in this library.

Here's a sample class I've made that helps you do it using this library:

```
public class Root
  {
  private static final Root _instance =new Root();
  private Boolean           _hasRoot  =null;
  private Shell.Interactive _rootSession;

  public interface IGotRootListener
    {
    public void onGotRootResult(boolean hasRoot);
    }

  public static Root getInstance()
    {
    return _instance;
    }

  public boolean hasRoot()
    {
    return _hasRoot!=null&&_hasRoot;
    }

  //should be called on the UI thread
  public void getRoot(final IGotRootListener listener)
    {
    if(_hasRoot!=null&&_hasRoot)
      {
      listener.onGotRootResult(true);
      return;
      }
    final AtomicReference<Interactive> rootSessionRef=new AtomicReference<>();
    rootSessionRef.set(new Shell.Builder().useSU().setWantSTDERR(true).setWatchdogTimeout(5).setMinimalLogging(true).open(new Shell.OnCommandResultListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onCommandResult(final int commandCode,final int exitCode,final List<String> output)
          {
          final boolean success=exitCode==Shell.OnCommandResultListener.SHELL_RUNNING;
          if(success)
            _rootSession=rootSessionRef.get();
          _hasRoot=success;
          listener.onGotRootResult(success);
          }
      }));
    }

... // TODO add functions to call commands via _rootSession.addCommand , only if got root
```

Still, if anyone has a solution to my original question, I would love to know about it.

Comment: have a look at afwall+ code which uses libsuperuser with interactive mode (RootShell.java and api.java)

Comment: But I also use this library, and I've already wrote a snippet here of how to do it. I only asked how to do it without the library, as my original question says.